# Oracle Row Limit

Tags: sql, oracle, rownum

I need to limit my results of my query.  I need to limit based on the ID not the number of rows.

```
ex: ID   EVENT EVENT_DESC
    __   _____ __________
    1723    1A    1A desc
    1723    1B    1B desc
    2214    2A    2A desc
    2214    2B    2B desc
```

I need to get the top 10 ten IDs not the top ten rows.  I'm not sure how to do this.  Can you point me to some doc that can help me achieve this?

Comment: Define "top".  Largest ID values?  Smallest ID values?  Values with the most rows?

Comment: I have a table the ID is the transaction#.  A transaction may have multiple events for one transaction.  For example transaction - 1723 may have event 1A, 1B, etc.  The rownumb is pulling the first 10 records.  I want to pull the first 10 transactions.  I ended up having to create a query within a query.  Get the 10 transaction IDs and then get the rest of the event data that was associated with those 10 transactions.  I just wanted to see if I could filter my results based on the transaction(ID) using the rownum.  Rownum was only getting 10 records and not 10 transactions.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT id, 
          event,
          event_desc,
          rank() over (order by id desc) as rnk
   FROM your_table
) 
WHERE rnk <= 10
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like this?

SQL Server

```
SELECT TOP 10 ID FROM TABLE
GROUP BY ID
```

Oracle

```
SELECT ID FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM TABLE ORDER BY ID
)
WHERE rownum <= 10
```

Comment: That won't (always) do what you're looking for in Oracle.  `rownum` doesn't imply any inherent ordering of the rows.  You'd want something like `select id from (select distinct id from table order by id) where rownum <=10`.  The ordering has to be done explicitly before the rownum filter is applied.

Comment: @DaveCosta Thank you, Dave. I updated the answer accordingly.